# Was Simon of Cyrene an accidental choice?

Tags: jesus, mark, passion

We read in Mark 15:21, of an incident in the Passion of Jesus:

> A certain man from Cyrene, Simon, the father of Alexander and Rufus, was passing by on his way in from the country, and they forced him to carry the cross.

Some versions like CEV mention that Simon was returning from farm. But, the event having happened in the noon, it was an unusual time for a farmer to return home.
From the way Mark mentions the names of Simon's  sons, it is implied that they  either were  disciples of Jesus at the time, or joined the group after the Lord's death and before recording of the Gospel. Though Mark narrates that Simon was just passing by on his way back from the country/ farm, it looks like he was there with the purpose of helping Jesus in the capacity of the disciples' father, but was afraid of disclosing his identity. My question therefore, is : Was Simon the Cyrene an accidental choice in the Passion of Jesus  ?

Comment: We are not told so we do not know.

Comment: Your assumption that mentioning sons means his sons were part of the group is not historically correct.  Several people in the Bible have the name Simon, which tells us that it was a common name, and people did not have family names back then.  If you wanted to identify someone, you'd either mention their trade or you'd mention other family members, to narrow down which Simon you meant.

Comment: Thanks, Graham. If Alexander and Rufus were not known to Mark, he would have used attributes for them too , like what the Jews did for Jesus, calling him the Carpenter's son.

Answer (score 2):

Every word in the Bible has a purpose. It was written with inspiration from the Holy Spirit to reveal what God wanted to say. Therefore, even the short summaries of people's lives that we see in the Bible are not there by accident.

Matthew 27:32 NKJV says :

> 32 Now as they came out, they found a man of Cyrene, Simon by name.
> Him **they compelled** to bear His cross.

Mark 15:21 NKJV says:

> 21 Then **they compelled** a certain man, Simon a Cyrenian, the father of
> Alexander and Rufus, as he was coming out of the country and passing
> by, to bear His cross.

Luke 23:26 NKJV says:

> 26 Now as they led Him away, they laid hold of a certain man, Simon a
> Cyrenian, who was coming from the country, and on him they laid the
> cross that he might **bear it after Jesus.**

The Bible does not explicitly state whether Simon of Cyrene was an accidental choice to help carry the cross of Jesus during the Passion. However, there are speculations about why Simon was chosen for this task.

Some suggest that Simon could have been specially selected by God to take part in Jesus' crucifixion.

According to this view, Simon's participation in carrying the cross can stand for the truth that **all Christians are called to share in some capacity in Christ's suffering.**

[biblestudytools](https://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-study/topical-studies/why-is-it-important-that-simon-of-cyrene-carried-the-cross.html) says:

> **God is always purposeful, and He may have directed the soldiers to
> choose Simon of Cyrene to carry the Lord’s cross for a portion of His
> travail to Golgotha.** We cannot lose sight of the fact that Immanuel
> (God with Us), the Creator (Colossians 1:16), the One Who carries our
> burdens (Psalm 55:22) accepted help from a man. What a lesson in
> humility. And we know that part of the execution process involved
> shameful, public humiliation. Simon did not merely spectate; he also
> partook in the Lord’s advance toward crucifixion.

> Matthew and Mark say Simon “was compelled” to carry the cross, while
> Luke says Simon “was seized” and had the cross laid on him. In each
> account, Simon is pressed into service. The passages do not say he
> volunteered. In a manner of spiritualizing what Simon did, some say
> **we, too, would rather not carry our “crosses.”**

> Luke’s Gospel says Simon carried the cross “behind Jesus.” Some also
> spiritualize Simon’s conveyance of Jesus’ cross in relation to how **we
> as believers are to “bear our own crosses” as we follow Jesus** (Luke
> 14:27). Simon of Cyrene provides us with an implicit illustration of
> what that looks like. It’s not easy to follow Jesus. The world system
> tries to sway us with its distractions and enticements, just as Simon
> most likely received taunts and offers as he carried the Lord’s
> burden.

> Scripture makes no direct mention of Simon of Cyrene after the
> Resurrection. **Tradition states Simon went to Egypt and shared the
> Gospel. After that, according to the apocryphal Acts of Simon and
> Judas, Simon was martyred in 100 A.D by being cut in half with a saw.**

Comment: Thanks, Jason_. Simon was engaged not because the Jewish leaders had sympathy for Jesus, but because they wanted him to undergo the shame and agony of crucifixion. If Simon himself came forward to help, they would have pushed him away ! So he had to feign ignorance of the proceedings, so that both himself and Jesus came out safe. Compare this with the Emmaus incidence where Jesus opts to continue his journey before being asked to stay put , by the disciples( Lk 24:28)